# Can we edit our profile details?

Tags: support, profile-page, mobile-app

Can we change our profile info like profile picture and name and if yes than how can we do so?

Can anyone help?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**NO**.

The app as well as the mobile site didn't have this feature.

But if you want to edit the profile,

- open the site in mobile browser
- Scroll to bottom and click on full site
- On full site, zoom it and click on your profile picture in the top nav bar
- Go to **Edit Profile & settings** tab and edit profile.

But it is somewhat difficult to edit the profile in mobile browser.

But you can't edit the profile in mobile app anyway.

Comment: Hey i can't find can u upload screenshots

Comment: @user41111 can't find what, exactly?